# Why does CMake + Include What You Use not print any output?

Tags: cmake, iwyu, include-what-you-use

I have installed Include What You Use.
I cloned the repository, checked out tag 0.18 and compiled.

```
$ include-what-you-use -v
clang version 14.0.0 (Fedora 14.0.0-1.fc36)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/12
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/12
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
```

I integrated the tool in CMake as follows:

```
find_program(iwyu_path NAMES include-what-you-use iwyu)
if(iwyu_path)
    message("Found iwyu")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE ${iwyu_path})
endif()
```

I run CMake:

```
$ CC="clang" CXX="clang++" cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE=include-what-you-use ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Found iwyu
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/...
```

And compile: `make`, but I don't see any IWYU output in the terminal.
Why is this the case?

Make's output:

```
[steddy@nowhere build]$ CC="clang" CXX="clang++" cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_INCLUDE_WHAT_YOU_USE=include-what-you-use ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found nlohmann_json: /usr/local/lib64/cmake/nlohmann_json/nlohmann_jsonConfig.cmake (found suitable version "3.10.5", minimum required is "3.10.5") 
Found iwyu
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build
[steddy@nowhere build]$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut -B/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/CMakeFiles /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
make  -f src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/build.make src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
make  -f src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/build.make src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[  6%] Building CXX object src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/body.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/body.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/body.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/body.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/body.cpp
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.cpp
[ 18%] Building CXX object src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node_json.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node_json.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node_json.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node_json.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node_json.cpp
In file included from /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node_json.cpp:1:
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.h:42:33: warning: inline function 'bh::Node::top_left' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
  [[nodiscard]] inline Vector2f top_left() const;
                                ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node_json.cpp:33:27: note: used here
       {"top_left", {node.top_left().x(), node.top_left().y()}},
                          ^
In file included from /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node_json.cpp:1:
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.h:46:30: warning: inline function 'bh::Node::length' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
  [[nodiscard]] inline float length() const;
                             ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node_json.cpp:34:24: note: used here
       {"length", node.length()},
                       ^
2 warnings generated.
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/force.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/barnes_hut/CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/force.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/force.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/force.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/force.cpp
In file included from /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/force.cpp:4:
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.h:46:30: warning: inline function 'bh::Node::length' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
  [[nodiscard]] inline float length() const;
                             ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/force.cpp:44:14: note: used here
    if (node.length() / distance < OMEGA) {
             ^
1 warning generated.
[ 31%] Linking CXX static library libbarnes_hut_lib.a
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/barnes_hut && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/llvm-ar qc libbarnes_hut_lib.a CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/body.cpp.o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node.cpp.o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/node_json.cpp.o CMakeFiles/barnes_hut_lib.dir/force.cpp.o
/usr/bin/llvm-ranlib libbarnes_hut_lib.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 31%] Built target barnes_hut_lib
make  -f src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/build.make src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
make  -f src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/build.make src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 37%] Building CXX object src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation/simulation.cpp
[ 43%] Building CXX object src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation_json.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation_json.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation_json.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation_json.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation/simulation_json.cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simple_simulator.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++ -DJSON_DIAGNOSTICS=0 -DJSON_USE_IMPLICIT_CONVERSIONS=1 -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -isystem /usr/local/include/eigen3 -std=c++17 -MD -MT src/simulation/CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simple_simulator.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simple_simulator.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simple_simulator.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation/simple_simulator.cpp
[ 56%] Linking CXX static library libsimulation_lib.a
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/src/simulation && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/llvm-ar qc libsimulation_lib.a CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation.cpp.o CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simulation_json.cpp.o CMakeFiles/simulation_lib.dir/simple_simulator.cpp.o
/usr/bin/llvm-ranlib libsimulation_lib.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 56%] Built target simulation_lib
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
make  -f tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/build.make tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 62%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/testlib.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++  -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation -std=c++17 -MD -MT tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/testlib.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/testlib.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/testlib.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/testlib.cpp
[ 68%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_quadtree.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++  -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation -std=c++17 -MD -MT tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_quadtree.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_quadtree.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_quadtree.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_quadtree.cpp
In file included from /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_quadtree.cpp:5:
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.h:42:33: warning: inline function 'bh::Node::top_left' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
  [[nodiscard]] inline Vector2f top_left() const;
                                ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_quadtree.cpp:25:16: note: used here
  REQUIRE(root.top_left() == Vector2f{0, 10});
               ^
In file included from /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_quadtree.cpp:5:
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut/node.h:46:30: warning: inline function 'bh::Node::length' is not defined [-Wundefined-inline]
  [[nodiscard]] inline float length() const;
                             ^
/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_quadtree.cpp:26:16: note: used here
  REQUIRE(root.length() == 10);
               ^
2 warnings generated.
[ 75%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_force.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++  -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation -std=c++17 -MD -MT tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_force.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_force.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_force.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_force.cpp
[ 81%] Building CXX object tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_body.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++  -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation -std=c++17 -MD -MT tests/CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_body.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_body.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_body.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/tests/test_body.cpp
[ 87%] Linking CXX executable testlib
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/testlib.cpp.o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_quadtree.cpp.o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_force.cpp.o CMakeFiles/testlib.dir/test_body.cpp.o -o testlib  ../src/barnes_hut/libbarnes_hut_lib.a ../src/simulation/libsimulation_lib.a ../src/barnes_hut/libbarnes_hut_lib.a 
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests && /usr/bin/cmake -D TEST_TARGET=testlib -D TEST_EXECUTABLE=/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests/testlib -D TEST_EXECUTOR= -D TEST_WORKING_DIR=/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests -D TEST_SPEC= -D TEST_EXTRA_ARGS= -D TEST_PROPERTIES= -D TEST_PREFIX= -D TEST_SUFFIX= -D TEST_LIST=testlib_TESTS -D TEST_REPORTER= -D TEST_OUTPUT_DIR= -D TEST_OUTPUT_PREFIX= -D TEST_OUTPUT_SUFFIX= -D CTEST_FILE=/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/tests/testlib_tests-b12d07c.cmake -P /usr/local/lib64/cmake/Catch2/CatchAddTests.cmake
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 87%] Built target testlib
make  -f apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/apps /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/apps /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
make  -f apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/build.make apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[ 93%] Building CXX object apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/apps && /usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" -- /usr/bin/clang++  -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/barnes_hut -I/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/src/simulation -std=c++17 -MD -MT apps/CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o -c /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/apps/app.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable app
cd /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/apps && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/app.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++ CMakeFiles/app.dir/app.cpp.o -o app  ../src/barnes_hut/libbarnes_hut_lib.a ../src/simulation/libsimulation_lib.a ../src/barnes_hut/libbarnes_hut_lib.a 
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
[100%] Built target app
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/steddy/CLionProjects/barnes-hut/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: `And compile: make` please post the output of `make VERBOSE=1`. Was everything compiled or did make run soe compilation commands?

Comment: I posted a link to Make's output at the bottom of the post.

Comment: `/usr/bin/cmake -E __run_co_compile --iwyu="/usr/local/bin/include-what-you-use;--driver-mode=g++" ...barnes_hut/body.cpp` well, it is used. IT could be it just doesn't output anything.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. When I invoke the tool standalone on a source file, it outputs some `include` mistakes; but it doesn't when I run it in conjunction with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

When [`cmake` invokes `include-what-you-use`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.22.1/Source/cmcmd.cxx?ref_type=tags#L341-354) it ignores any error return codes, and only prints output that contains `should remove...` or `should add...`. So if there are any errors running `include-what-you-use`, it prints nothing at all.

You can probably diagnose the error by running `include-what-you-use` manually using the compile options from the verbose `make`.